# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'

Tags: python, twilio

I am getting an SSL error using twilio.  Anybody have any suggestions?

#### Error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "communication_easy/that_guy/communicate.py", line 4, in <module>
>     from twilio.rest import Client
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twilio/rest/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
>     from twilio.http.http_client import TwilioHttpClient
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twilio/http/http_client.py", line 1, in <module>
>     from requests import Request, Session, hooks
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
>     from urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
>     import OpenSSL.SSL
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
>     from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 118, in <module>
>     SSL_ST_INIT = _lib.SSL_ST_INIT
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'
> ```

#### Code:

```
import random
from twilio.rest import Client

TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = "asdfasdfsdfsdf"
TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN  = "asdfasdfasdfasf"
TWILIO_NUMBER = "+5555555"


def send_text(body, target_phone_number):
    client = Client(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)
    message = client.messages.create(body=body, from_=TWILIO_NUMBER, to=target_phone_number)

send_text(blah, blah)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this github ticket](https://github.com/andresriancho/w3af/issues/15260#issuecomment-286279722), the problem can be solved by upgrading to `pyOpenSSL>=16.2.0`

Try:

```
pip install pyOpenSSL -U
```

Comment: ty. I did that but it defaulted `pip` to python3...does using pip default to python3 now if you dont mind?

Comment: Which pip depends on the OS and distribution and...  Find your python install dir with `which python` or `where python`.  Use the pip in the scripts directory there.

Comment: `$ which python
/usr/bin/python
`

Comment: That may be the default python from the distribution.  I would suggest trying both `pip2` and `pip3` to see which works for your situation.